# Infinite horizontal scrolling div with repeating elements - circular navigation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

I need to create a sort of circular navigation bar with images as links. By circular, I think that the elements should be repeated. At first, I thought this would be a trivial task but turns out it's not that easy.

Let's say that images are represented as numbers in array [1,2,3]

Currently active index is 1 (the image represented with the numbers 2)

What should be shown on the screen is

3 1 (2) 3 1

And the user could go either left, or right and new images would be shown on the screen.

If he goes one to the right, the new pattern of images that would be shown on the screen is:

1 2 (3) 1 2

Etc.

The animation of the div moving to the right is also necessary.

What would be the correct way to do that? I have a sense that it could be done with making the div overflow-x scrollable but I am wondering if there is a smarter way to achieve the same thing, maybe by using canvas?

If anyone has an idea of how to do this, please let me know. Either code or concepts would be greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: You can repurpose the carousel example provided here https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/carousel